# "AttributeError at /" authentication - Django 1.8

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, python-3.4, django-1.8

I am trying to get a login system to work for a Django project I am working on. However I keep exceptions like :

> 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'

Pretty much I want to use the django authentication system. So this is what I have so far:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    height = models.FloatField()
    weight = models.FloatField()
    medical_information = models.ForeignKey(MedicalInformation, null=True)
    emergency_contact = models.ForeignKey(EmergencyContact, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(UserStatus, null=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['weight', 'height', 'date_of_birth', 'phone_number', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

I do this so I can get more information on the user.

Further in the views.py file I have:

```
def user_login(request):
  if request.POST:
    email = request.POST.get("email").lower()
    password = request.POST.get("password")
    context = {}

    if not all([password, email]):
        context['error_message'] = "Please enter email & password"

    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

    if user is None:
        context['error_message'] = "Incorrect Username/Password"

    login(request, user)
    redirect('dashboard')

  return render(request, 'login.html')
```

I keep reading that you have to call `user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)` before you call `login(request, user)` which I am doing within the views.py file.

In my settings I have the following as well:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

I don't know what else I need to show but let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
def dashboard(request):
    """
    shows over the system
    """
    print("dashboard")
```

Comment: Can you show the view where you redirect to after login?

Comment: @Gocht Updated with the view that gets the redirect.

Comment: The error message is clear, In somewhere you are asking for the `.backend` attribute in a `User` object, but I can't see where here, you could check your code.

Comment: Check your "dashboard", probably have something like user.backend.

Comment: Can you try adding the backend in the view like user.backend="django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend" like in your settings.py